# ng-bootstrap drop down tab

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

How do I put a drop down menu triggered from a tab..

```
<ngb-tabset>
    <ngb-tab title="tab1">
        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
            Tab 1 content
        </ng-template>
    </ngb-tab>
    <ngb-tab title="tab2">
        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
            Tab 2 content
        </ng-template>
    </ngb-tab>
</ngb-tabset>
```

I need to have a carret as part of the title which would display a number of options. I can achieve this in straight bootstrap like this..

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">
          Tab 2
          <a style="display: inline;" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <b class="caret"></b>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <a tabindex="-1" (click)="doSomething()">Option 1</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </a>
      </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
</div>
```

I was hoping this could be done in angular bootstrap but I don't think it can. Please prove me wrong..

Comment: Well, just put the dropdown inside the ngbTabTitle of the tab: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hgoye9?file=app/tabset-basic.html. I find it extremely weird and unituitive, but it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will put this as the answer unless you want the credit.

Comment: @JB Nizel Can you align individual tabs to the right with these as well, e.g if you wanted a save button to appear aligned vertically with tab titles but pulled to the right. Seems only justify input on tabset which aligns all tabs.

Comment: I don't get what you mean, sorry. You should probably ask another question, with a sketch of what you ant to achieve.